# Startup Expirable Equity

Tags: stocks, start-up, equity

I  own a startup that is user-based. We are close to finishing  the building of the prototype so therefore it has no users, no revenues, nor any investment.

I have 4 unpaid co-op students working full-time for a term. In order to encourage them and value their work, I would like  to share equity with them, preferably equities that expire after 1 year since their co-op ends after 3 months and they probably won't be at the start-up anymore.

We will be launching soon and will probably generate some but not much revenue. The idea is to provide `expirable equities` for  them to split the revenues generated within a year.

I did some research and could not find anything such as `expirable equities.` Does something like this exist in financial terms? If so, what would it be called? What percentage do you think I should give them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing seems to be a [revenue sharing agreement](https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/010915/how-does-revenue-sharing-work-practice.asp). As to the percentage, this is situation-specific and would therefore be difficult to answer as the question is currently asked. For example, a few thought starters:

- What *can* you share from your projected revenues ?
- How much incentive do you wish to give with this agreement ?
- What are the expectations of your co-op students ?
- What are the applicable laws and regulations in your area that may prevent or mandate you to do this ?
- What are the tax implications of the agreement for both the co-op students and yourself ?